# How to save object having field with custom validator using spring boots?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

Can anyone please help me why I can’t save object having field with custom validator in the spring boots?

Scenario:
First I have to validate the field by custom validator(which is working fine) then save entity into the database(which breaks).
I am using Spring boots framework on IntelliJ IDE. The code is on github. https://github.com/mhussainshah1/customvalidation

I have Customer entity

```java
@Entity
public class Customer {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
 
    @ContactInfo //Custom Validator
    @NotNull
    private String contactInfo;
 
    // standard constructor, getters, setters
}
```

I have ContactInfoExpression entity

```java
@Entity
public class ContactInfoExpression {
 
    @Id
    @Column(name="expression_type")
    private String type;
  
    private String pattern;
 
    //standard constructor, getters, setters
}
```

I have `ContactInfoExpressionRepository` and `CustomerRepository`
which extends `CrudRepository<T, Id>`

I use an H2 in-memory database with the following configuration in the application.properties file. The `contactInfoType` property can be set to one of the values email, phone or website

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

contactInfoType=email
#contactInfoType=phone
#contactInfoType=website
```

Custom Validator

```java
@Component
public class ContactInfoValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ContactInfo, String> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(ContactInfoValidator.class);

    @Value("${contactInfoType}")
    private String expressionType;

    private String pattern;

    @Autowired
    private ContactInfoExpressionRepository contactInfoExpressionRepository;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ContactInfo contactInfo) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmptyOrWhitespace(expressionType)) {
            LOG.error("Contact info type missing!");
        } else {
            pattern = contactInfoExpressionRepository.findById(expressionType)
                    .map(ContactInfoExpression::getPattern).get();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmptyOrWhitespace(pattern)) {
            return Pattern.matches(pattern, value);
        }
        LOG.error("Contact info pattern missing!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Custom Constraint Annotation

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = { ContactInfoValidator.class })
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ContactInfo {
    String message() default "Invalid value";
 
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
 
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

I use class DataLoader to load data

```java
@Component
public class DataLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ContactInfoExpressionRepository contactInfoExpressionRepository;

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        String pattern = "[a-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";
        ContactInfoExpression email = new ContactInfoExpression("email", pattern);
        contactInfoExpressionRepository.save(email);

        pattern = "^([0-9]( |-)?)?(\\(?[0-9]{3}\\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})$";
        ContactInfoExpression phone = new ContactInfoExpression("phone", pattern);
        contactInfoExpressionRepository.save(phone);

        pattern = "^(http:\\/\\/www\\.|https:\\/\\/www\\.|http:\\/\\/|https:\\/\\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\\-\\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\\/.*)?$";
        ContactInfoExpression website = new ContactInfoExpression("website", pattern);
        contactInfoExpressionRepository.save(website);

        Customer customer1 = new Customer("mhussainshah79@gmail.com");
        customerRepository.save(customer1);// Error: can`t save
    }
}
```

I can`t save the customer object having field with custom validator. I am getting the following error at runtime

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000032: Unable to initialize com.example.customvalidation.ContactInfoValidator.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.customvalidation.ContactInfoValidator.initialize(ContactInfoValidator.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.customvalidation.ContactInfoValidator.initialize(ContactInfoValidator.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Any error/issue?

Comment: I have edited my post with errors. I am using IntelliJ IDE for development.  Complete code is on github.https://github.com/mhussainshah1/customvalidation .

Comment: The validation is a configuration, not a component?

Comment: There is no need to put `@Configuration` or `@Component` annotation because springboot initiate the custom validator at start. The solution to the problem is to add `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode: none` in the application.properties file.

Comment: Far too much code for this site. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to add the following in the `application.properties` file.

`properties spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode:none`

Reference:
How to avoid double validation in Spring Boot applications, Sanjay Patel, 15 May, 2018
https://www.naturalprogrammer.com/blog/16386/switch-off-jpa-validation-spring-boot